# python return custom objects

Tags: python, object

Long time .NET programmer, newbie Python learner.

In .NET if you want to fetch a customer record from the database and do something with the info in the UI, you might do it like this

```
Customer customer = ReadCustomerRecord (12345)
```

Customer is a custom object containing a couple dozens fields about the customer. ReadCustomerRecord connects to a database reads the record and populates the fields in the Customer object and then returns it.

Now, I'm not understanding how you do the same thing in Python. If I'm just returning the customer object from a method that is doing the initialization, how to I tell the code what type of object it is?

Comment: Could you please provide a piece of code describing your dificulty?

Comment: You don't need to tell Python what type of object it is. In Python, type information is stored with the *data*, not the variable.

Comment: What, exactly are you asking. Are you asking how to write user-defined classes in Python? Because you specifically ask "how to I tell the code what type of object it is?" in which case, the answer is that in Python you don't.

Comment: In python you can do `x = 2` and right after do `x = "hello"`. There's no static typing

Comment: Now, if you want to check if a particular object has a specific type, you can use `isisntance(obj, type)` for instances and `issubclass(obj.__class__, type) for classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Python *does* have optional static typing if you want it. The syntax is a little different from C#, but it's the same as many other languages:

```
customer: Customer = ReadCustomerRecord(12345)
```

If you then run your code through Mypy, or another static type checker or analyzer (many IDEs have then integrated, so you don't have to do anything), it will be able to verify that the only things you ever store in `customer` are values of `Customer` type, and you never do anything with it that isn't legal for values of that type.

---

However, even if you're using static type checking, you don't need to specify the type of every variable, because most of them can be automatically inferred. Again, this is different from C#, but it's the same as many other languages—including statically-typed languages with stricter rules and more powerful type systems than C# like Swift, Rust, or F#.

"Inference" means that if you don't specify a type, the static checker figures out that `customer` must be a `Customer` because that's what `ReadCustomerRecord` returns. And then it can verify all the same stuff as before.

Just as in Swift or Go, it's idiomatic in Python to not specify the types of variables unless it's either showing something non-obvious or otherwise helpful to human readers, or resolving something ambiguous to the static checker.

Among modern languages, it's really only the languages in the C family (C, C++, Java, C#, etc.) that require you to specify the type of everything by name even when it's blindingly obvious—and even many of them give you something like `auto` that can be used to tell the compiler to infer the type.

---

But the big difference between Python and the other languages I mentioned is that Python is dynamically typed. The static checker can verify your variable types, but the actual compiler and interpreter don't care about them. In fact, under the covers, variables don't actually have types at all.

In Python, it's *values* that have types. Variables are just names for values, and it's perfectly legal (and sometimes idiomatic) to reuse the same name for different values of different types at different times.

Static checking is there to prove that you're not using dynamic features when you think you aren't, and it gets out of the way when you want those dynamic features.

---

Occasionally, you want a bunch of related stuff to be statically checked, but you have one variable in there where you're depending on duck typing. For that, you can opt that variable out even from your opt-in typing by calling it an `Any`.

---

So, you probably just want to write that line as:

```
customer = ReadCustomerRecord(12345)
```

But if it's not clear to the reader what type this would be, you can do this:

```
customer: Customer = ReadCustomerRecord(12345)
```

And if you need to use duck typing with `customer` but static type-check everything else around it:

```
customer: Any = ReadCustomerRecord(12345)
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was asking. Thanks for understanding the question.

Comment: Notice that this syntax is specific for `python3`, and that it will not yield errors as `c#` would yield if there are type mismatches; i.e. the command `x: int = "hello"` works, and `x` gets to be a `str` instead of `int` even though you made explicit to the reader that it is an `int`.

Comment: @RafaelC I start off by saying "If you then run your code through MyPy…" and later devote an entire section to "The static checker can verify your variable types, but the actual compiler and interpreter don't care about them…"

Comment: @RafaelC As for Python3: It's 2018. Python 2.7 is less than 2 years away from end of support. I don't think it's necessary to complicate every answer by explaining Python 2 anymore, unless there's some reason to believe the OP is using Python 2. Especially in this case, where it would require describing either the comment syntax or typeshed files and the tools you can use to convert to annotations when you later upgrade, which makes everything much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Look into Python classes.

Example

```
class Customer:
    #constructor, self == this
    def __init__(self, data):
         self.data = data

def ReadCustomerRecord (cust_id):
    ## get from db
    cust = Customer(data)
    return cust

customer = ReadCustomerRecord(1234)
```

Python is a dynamically typed-language meaning that type-checking is done during the runtime of the program. All types are implicit, in fact methods can return varying types based on the condition.

```
def func(is_list):
    if is_list:
        return [1,2,3]
    else:
        return 1
```

Comment: Your point still stands that types are implicit, but this: "meaning objects can be converted to various types without explicit casting" is definitely not correct.

Comment: You are correct, i made a slight correct to clarify

Comment: "is a dynamically typed-language meaning objects are of a single base type named object allowing for multiple derived types to be the return type of a function." is still not correct. All that dynamic typing means is that type checking is done at runtime. Python *variables* aren't typed, so variables can reference objects of any type. Note, many *statically* typed OOP languages derive all objects from a single type, so that isn't really relevant

Comment: fixed, thx for the clarifications, i  misused dynamic-typing and weak typing